# Spring4D field injection does not work in a TForm instance

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I would like to use the `Inject` attribute of `Spring4D` release 1.1 just like in the sample code below. It seems the Inject attribute has no effect because the fMyResource field value is NIL in the button click handler method. In my original code the type registration got place in the dpr file before `Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);`. I just modify it to make the code more concise. What should I do to make the field injection work?

```
unit FieldInjectionTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Spring.Container.Common;

type
  IMyResource = interface
    ['{6BD6421E-F57F-41BD-A6E4-347B2BE20A3C}']
    procedure foo;
  end;

  TMyResource = class ( TInterfacedObject, IMyResource )
    public
      procedure foo; virtual;
  end;

  TForm1 = class ( TForm )
      button1 : TButton;
      procedure Button1Click( sender : TObject );
    private
      [Inject]
      fMyResource : IMyResource;

  end;

implementation

uses
  Spring.Container;

procedure TMyResource.foo;
begin
  //...
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click( sender : TObject );
begin
  // fMyResource is NIL
  fMyResource.foo;
end;

initialization
  globalContainer.registerType<TMyResource>.implements<IMyResource>;
  globalContainer.build;

end.
```

Comment: You might consider changing the q title since it is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @MartynA I did not work to me. So from my point of view it was right. But i will modify it : ... + in a TForm instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@whorsdaddy's comment help me to understand : The `[Inject]` attribute works just in container managed objects. It is not so surprising when I rethink it.

Comment: yes indeed. You can always use globalcontainer.resolve<> instead